# how I can change the default message when the table is empty

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable like this:

```
       <p:dataTable rowStyleClass="#{(item.vigente) eq true ? 'hh1' : 'hh2'}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" id="tabla_Contratos"  var="item" selection="#{suplementosMB.contratoParaSuplemSelected}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{item.idContrato}" value="#{contratosMB.itemsContratosUtil}"> 
                            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{suplementosMB.mostrarTablaSuplementos}"  update=":form2:tabla_Suplementos :form2:panelDetallesSuplementos :form2:growl"/>  
                            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"  update=":form2:growl"/> 
                            <p:column id="ctipo" headerText="Seleccione el contrato">                         
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.noContrato}/#{item.tipoContrato.tipoContrato}"/>
                                <p:commandButton id="estado" icon="#{contratosMB.definirIconEstadoContrato(item.vigente)}" title="#{(item.vigente) eq true ? 'Estado del contrato: Vigente' : 'Estado del contrato: Cancelado'}" style="left:20px;width:25px"/>
                            </p:column> 
        </p:dataTable>
```

when table is empty show: "No records found" , how can i change this message

Comment: Do a guess which attribute it would be: http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/dataTable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [documenation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/dataTable.html) first. You can change the message by setting `emptyMessage`.